# Apache mod_sed - "OutputSed not allowed here" in htaccess

Tags: apache-2.4, apache2

I'm trying to use `mod_sed` to replace strings in HTML, using `.htaccess`.

According to the `mod_sed` [docs](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_sed.html), this should be possible as the module supports use in `.htaccess`.

However, I can't see any examples online that actually do this (instead of using the module inside `<Location>` tags), and the following `.htaccess` contents triggers 500 `OutputSed not allowed here` in the server log:

```
FilterDeclare APPBASEHREF
FilterProvider APPBASEHREF Sed "%{Content_Type} = 'text/html'"
FilterChain APPBASEHREF
OutputSed "s/<base data-app-base-href href=\"/<base href=\"%{ENV:BASE}/ni"
SetOutputFilter OutputSed;DEFLATE
```

I'd put my experience with Apache server config at "low", so I'd appreciate it if anyone could point out any potential errors.

Is `mod_sed` docs just incorrect, or do I need to explicitly enable `mod_sed` to work in `.htaccess`, or is something wrong with permissions somewhere?

For reference, I'm on Apache v2.4.29 and `AllowOverride All` is set in the virtual host file.

Comment: The docs refer to "AddOutputFilter Sed html " directive, have you tried?

Comment: @bgtvfr yes and it makes no difference, whether using old `AddOutputFilter` or new `FilterProvider`, the filter seems to get registered without any issues, and it's the `OutputSed` directive that's causing the issue